# How do I exclude the Main Menu contribution of an included plugin in eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP plugin project whose plugin.xml provides a main menu contribution. I have now started a new plugin and added my old plugin as a dependency (because I want to use some of it's views without having 2 code bases).

The problem is the included project's menu contribution is showing in my new project, how can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Look at the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point